# How to script saving Ten thousand dollars in 100 days. So that I can figure out on any given day how much money I have

Tags: python, math, currency

Say I wanted to put money in an envelope(variable called envelope) each day in increments of $1 each day. so for example I started with 1$ the first day, than on the next day I added $2 on the third day I added $3 and so on and so forth. If I wanted to write this using a while loop or for loop how would it look.

so far I have the notes worked out.

something like...

```
for i in xrange(100): ##100 for 100 days
    
    i = 2 
    
    x += 1
    
    x=x+i
return x
```

I am pretty sure this is wrong. how would you write it.

the objective is to write something that would help me to figure out how much money I had on any given day. like on day 71 how much would that be.

Comment: If you use some maths, you can work it out without a loop. Something like `n * (n+1) / 2`

Comment: That story is over 200 years old: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Anecdotes

Answer (score 0):

Your code will look like this:

```
days = 100
total = 0
for i in range(days):
 total += i+1
return total
```

You can simply use range() in Python 3+.

Answer (score 0):

THe function could look something like that

```py
def amount_of_savings(number_of_days,amount_per_day):
    
    total_amount = 0
    
    for day in range(number_of_days):
        
        total_amount += amount_per_day
        
        
    return total_amount
```

Then call the function

```py
amount_of_savings(100,5) # 100 days, 5$ per day
>>> 500
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store it in an array and get back the index which is the n-th date you want the value of

```
money = []
initialMoney = 1
for i in range(100): ##100 for 100 days
    initialMoney += i
    money.append(initialMoney)
    

getNDayMoney = 71
print(money[getNDayMoney])
```